# Trackpad handwriting does not work

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, handwriting

On my MBP M1, handwriting input options work as designed all the way until it comes to actually drawing strokes. At that point, nothing shows up: it’s a blank “Handwriting” mini-window and nothing happens to it regardless of chosen language or what I do with the trackpad.

- I know how it’s supposed to work: I used it lots on my old Intel MBP where it was never a problem, it only broke shortly after my migration to Apple Silicon and simultaneously Big Sur back when it came out.
- I did a clean install when Monterey came out, and it resolved the issue probably for a month or so. I’m not inclined to do a reinstall again or full OS reset in near future. For now when I need to hand-write a character (that I don’t know how to type by other means) I do it on the phone and then copy-paste.
- I’m almost sure I am unintentionally causing it (because how can a feature be so horribly broken for so many OS releases?) but I can’t seem to pinpoint how, perhaps someone has encountered a similar situation.

Found only one report of a similar issue:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254489155. Resolved by wiping OS settings. As mentioned before, I know this would fix it for a while but obviously it’s not a proper solution.

Example of a *different* issue:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253892462: input option disappears and has to be reenabled. I never had this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, this is the solution from a Chinese forum, and it works!

System setting > accessibility > zoom > switch off “use trackpad gesture to zoom”

Comment: Can’t thank you enough, this issue caused me so much frustration until now!